# Magento category description on frontpage

Tags: php, magento, categories

I have a Magento shop and want to display the top-categories with description and image on the frontpage. Does anyone know how i can fix this?

I have this to display the top-categories:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But i can't get it showing also the description and image.
Hope someone can help me with this.

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using module:

Note: In this approach, you can display the block where you want to display(Home page, footer, sidebar, other pages).

**Steps:**
Here,
[Namespace]=**Codilar** &
[ModuleName]=**Category**

**Create xml** : app/etc/modules/Codilar_Category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Codilar_Category>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Codilar_Category>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Create config.xml**: app/code/local/Codilar/Category/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Codilar_Category>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Codilar_Category>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <codilar_category>
        <class>Codilar_Category_Block</class>
      </codilar_category>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <codilar_category>
        <class>Codilar_Category_Model</class>
      </codilar_category>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Create Model**: app/code/local/Codilar/Category/Model/Category.php

```
<?php
class Codilar_Category_Model_Category extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
public function getActiveCategory() {
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addIsActiveFilter();
    return $categories;
  }
}
```

**Create Block**: app/code/local/Codilar/Category/Block/Category.php

```
 <?php
    class Codilar_Category_Block_Category extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
      public function getActiveCategory() {
        $arr_categories = array();
        $categories = Mage::getModel("codilar_category/category")->getActiveCategory();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
          $arr_categories[] = array(
            'id' => $category->getId(),
            'name' => $category->getName(),
            'url' => $category->getProductUrl(),
            'image' => $category->getThumbnail(),
            'desc' => $category->getDescription(),
          );
        }
        return $arr_categories;
      }
    }
```

**Create template file**: 
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/codilar/category/category.phtml

```
    <?php
    $categories = $this->getActiveCategory();
    ?>
    <div id="category_list">
      <h1>All Category</h1>
      <?php if (is_array($categories) && count($categories)) { ?>
        <?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
          <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $category['url'] ?>"><?php echo $category['name'] ?></a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'. $category['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['image'] ?>" height="100" width="100">
          </div>
        <div>
        <p><?php echo $category['desc'] ?></p>
      </div>
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

To insert your category custom block using the layout update file, you can use the following code.

```
<block type="codilar_category/category" name="codilar_category_category" template="codilar/category/category.phtml"></block>
```

On the other hand, if you want to display your category custom block using the CMS page, here is the code you should use.

```
{{block type="codilar_category/category" name="codilar_category_category" template="codilar/category/category.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Hi Shahed, Thank you so much for this, but i only get a blank screen. When i change the type to core/template i get to see the <h1>All category</h1> but nothing else. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hello. No need to change type. The module is working fine for me. Did you followed all steps?

Comment: Check this tutorial. You will understand how the module works.
Links: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-block-development-in-magento--cms-23104

Comment: Hi Shahed, yes i followed all steps and checked it twice after that. I will check the tutorial. But i don't know why it's not showing anything :(

Comment: It works!! I had to add the block type to the whitelist System > Permissions > Blocks. Thank you so much!!! :D

Comment: One question :) Is it also possible to get only the top level categories? And maybe show the latest 2 products per category? ;)

Comment: I already managed to get only the top level categories, just add: ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2). Now i only need to displat 2 latest products of each category.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Create one function in model to get products collection. And pass it to phtml via block. And filter it by category id. Or using mage helper collect product collection in phtml & pass category id to filter and just display 2 product using loop.

Comment: I've added some new code in my comment, i can't figure out how to fix the 2 products showing up with the price, description, image etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working to show 2 products from each top level category with te following code:

> 

```
                    $count = 0;

                    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId)
                        ->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->setOrder('date', 'ASC');
                    ?>

                    <div class="home-featured-product">         
                        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                            <li class="item">

                                <div class="regular">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(270, 200); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>
                                </a>

                                <?php $productObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());?>
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($productObject, true) ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php
                            if($count == 1) break; // Stop after 2 items
                            $count++; 
                        ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>
```

But i also need to show the description and price but somehow the getPriceHtml doesn't seem to work :(